# cant unwrap the promise returned by the dispatched thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, unwrap

I don't know what I'm missing here

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are importing `useAppDispatch` and not `useDispatch`.[useAppDispatch](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type).